# Adding metadata to AST OCaml

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree

I have created an AST where the grammar has been defined as:

```
type expr =
| Cons of const
| Var of string
| List of ( expr list )
| Sum of ( expr * expr )
| Less_than of ( expr * expr ) 
| Conditional of ( expr * expr * expr )
| Array_literal of ( expr )
| Array_read of ( expr * expr )
```

I wanted to add some metadata to this ast. Metadata such as line number, char number tracking and more. How should I go about this? How should I declare my astNode? Should it look like :

```
type 'a astNode = 
{
data: 'a;
metadata: meta;
}
```

Other than this, how can I store this information? Will I have to store it at the time of parsing the tree? If that is the case, how do I transfer this information from a parse tree to AST?

I am fairly new to compilers and OCaml itself. So, any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Your direction is correct.  OCaml compiler source code does exactly the same thing as your idea: a record to carry the AST description often called `xxx_desc` and other attributes to the node.  How to build ASTs with these attributes and so on... it is too wide to answer, as someone close-voted.  You should come back with some more concrete questions with your trial code.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've decided to go with the Lexing.position module present in OCaml to remove some of the overhead. However, I am still not able to grasp when I should update my AST with the metadata node. i.e. what my grammar for that node would look like. Link to new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49046135/5275130

Comment: You first have to update your `expr` with the meta data.  I repeat.  Check OCaml source code.  Type `expression` of file `parsing/parsetree.mli` is what you want, but for a full scale programming language.

Comment: apparently, you posted mostly the same question twice, let's close one, and keep another. I've arbitrary chose one, and provided an answer to it.